# Windows update using svchost.exe?

Tags: windows, windows-update, processing, svchost

Lately I have been experiencing a lot of computers on our network being bogged down by svchost.exe. Nearly 50-100% CPU usage is associated with this process and I can't seem to figure out how to nix the issue. The most recent updates are applied but it still continues to run svchost.exe and most of the time, several instances which switch between "hogging" the processing power. Does anyone know how to get rid of this process from taking so much processing power all together?

Comment: First, start by identifying the service(s) involved.  You can do this with the Resource Monitor.

Comment: Resource Monitor?

Comment: Which version of Windows?

Comment: Get [ProcessExplorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx), run it, double-click the instance of `svchost` with the high CPU usage, click the *Services* tab, note down the services hosted by that instance, open `services.msc`, then for each of the listed services, stop it and see if the CPU usage goes down. Once you have identified the service that is pegging the CPU, it will be much easier to figure out what the problem is.

Comment: Willing to bet it's Windows Update. See https://www.google.com/search?q=windows+update+svchost+cpu+usage

Comment: @Nick: to the best of my knowledge, those issues were resolved years ago.  At any rate, the first page of search results look to all be obsolete.

Comment: We don't have enough data to give you an accurate answer. As mentioned in other comments we need the Windows version and more details about which svchost is taking so much CPU. You jump to fast to the conclusion that Windows Update is implied in this problem...

Comment: Ok few things 1. Does it do it when you stop the Automatic updates service? 2. Does it do it with the network lead out? If yes then virus maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1: Find out what services svchost is controlling. Open up Task Manager, right-click a svchost that is sucking up lots of resources, and click "Go to Service(s)". This will show you the services that are taking up your resources.

Step 2: Disable the unwanted services, or uninstall them if you dont need them.